# Ubuntu monospace font on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: feature-request, design, font

[Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com/)'s [monospace variant](http://font.ubuntu.com/#charset-mono-regular) has been released recently - is it possible to have it as the default monospace font on AU?

Comment: @Jin Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe it's just because I'm viewing the site on Ubuntu 11.10, but I already see Ubuntu Mono being used for code blocks and such.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Correct. If you, however, view it from other releases, distro or, heaven forbid, Windows, you won't see them in Ubuntu Mono.

Answer (score 7):

It'd be great to get it for tag text and codeblocks:

```
.post-tag
{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono Regular', 'Ubuntu Beta', UbuntuBeta, Ubuntu;
}

code
{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono Regular', "Ubuntu Mono", "Ubuntu Beta Mono A", "Consolas", monospace;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `, monospace` on the end of at least the `code` one?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Duh, maybeeee :P